# Extracting any 2 rows from a df that satisfy conditions - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter, difference, haversine

I am trying to use a df ( sampled with 7 rows below) to extract any two rows that satisfy 3 conditions:

1. Distance between 1st location less than x miles Using Haversine
2. Distance between 2nd location less than x miles Using Haversine
3. Difference between created time less than x minutes

Haversine would just be simple built in python

example as

```
from haversine import haversine

lyon = (45.7597, 4.8422) # (lat, lon)
paris = (48.8567, 2.3508)

haversine(lyon, paris, unit='mi')
243.71201856934454  # in miles
```

When I say difference between the 1st location thats the difference between the 1st location only, not taking into account the 2nd location or 2nd coordinates ( so difference of x miles between any two orders 1st location and difference of x miles between any two orders 2nd location)

```
       DAY     Order  1st_latitude  1st_longitude 2nd_latitude 2nd_longitude    created_time
        1/3/19  234e    32.69        -117.1          32.63      -117.08   3/1/19 19:00
        1/3/19  235d    40.73        -73.98          40.73       -73.99   3/1/19 23:21
        1/3/19  253w    40.76        -73.99          40.76       -73.99   3/1/19 15:26
        2/3/19  231y    36.08        -94.2           36.07       -94.21   3/2/19 0:14
        3/3/19  305g    36.01        -78.92          36.01       -78.95   3/2/19 0:09
        3/3/19  328s    36.76        -119.83         36.74       -119.79  3/2/19 4:33
        3/3/19  286n    35.76        -78.78          35.78       -78.74   3/2/19 0:43
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: I can't understand `Distance between 1st location`. Can you give an example of step-by-step calculation?

Comment: Sorry - the distance between the 1st location would be any orders in the dataframe that are less than x miles away from each other or are x miles away from each other.

So using Haversine would calc the difference between row ones 1st lat and 1st long and row twos 1st lat and 1st long, does that make sense? @giser_yugang

Comment: @Chris90  you should come up with your conditions that evaluate to `True` or `False`, then input them into the answer I've given.

Comment: I understand what your answer is but I dont know how to apply it to calculating the differences between the rows in the dataframe

Answer (score -1):

The general syntax is:

```
answerdf = df.loc[df[<cond1> & <cond2> & <cond3>]]
```

Come up with your own conditions to replace in the above and you'll get your answer because your question is not providing a clear explanation of what your conditions are

Example of a `<cond>`:

`haversine((df['1st_latitude'], df['1st_longitude']),(df['2nd_latitude'], df['2nd_longitude']) , unit='mi') > 100`

When placed into the above:

```
answerdf = df.loc[df[haversine((df['1st_latitude'], df['1st_longitude']),(df['2nd_latitude'], df['2nd_longitude']) , unit='mi') > 100]]
```

Comment: Sorry but - I have the conditions written out and numbered from 1-3?

conditions are that the 1st location coordinates distance must be less than x miles,
same for 2nd locations coordinates and the difference in created time must be less than x minutes.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I dont know how to apply the conditions to the calculations in the rows of the dataframe

Comment: @Chris90, your conditions are not in code form. By code form it is something like `haversine((df['1st_latitude'], df['1st_longitude']),(df['2nd_latitude'], df['2nd_longitude']) , unit='mi') > 100`

Comment: But I am not looking for the haversine distance of the 1st and 2nd location...only the distance difference of the 1st location of each row.  then the difference in miles of the 2nd location per row

Comment: the answer is looking at the difference between the 1st and 2nd coordinates that is not what I am looking for. 

I want to output a dataframe that contains all records that are within x miles of each others 1st location coordinates, the same for 2nd location and difference of  x mins for the time field

Comment: Difference requires a subtraction, what are your 2 values for subtraction based on that table you provided?

Comment: Difference would be for the created time column. So I want any 2 orders that have a difference of lets say 3 minutes for order creation time. I am not looking for the difference of two fields of one row, but the difference of that one field in all the rows.

I am trying to find any 2 rows that satisfy those parameters between each other

Comment: @Chris90, you're jumbling things together at once and it is difficult to write and understand for that. Separate out your conditions and give expected output in your question. Use the table in your answer to illustrate your answer and provide the 2 values I asked. Do it 1 condition at a time.

Comment: Ok im sorry - should I create a new question and delete this for confusion?

Comment: I tried to rephrase the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039498/identifying-groups-of-two-rows-that-satisfy-three-conditions-in-a-dataframe

@ycx