# Identifying groups of two rows that satisfy three conditions in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, filter, haversine

I have the df below and want to identify any two orders that satisfy all the following condtions:

1. Distance between pickups less than X miles
2. Distance between dropoffs less Y miles
3. Difference between order creation times less Z minutes

Would use haversine import haversine to calculate the difference in pickups for each row and difference in dropoffs for each row or order.

The df I currently have looks like the following:

```
  DAY   Order  pickup_lat  pickup_long     dropoff_lat dropoff_long  created_time
 1/3/19  234e    32.69        -117.1          32.63      -117.08   3/1/19 19:00
 1/3/19  235d    40.73        -73.98          40.73       -73.99   3/1/19 23:21
 1/3/19  253w    40.76        -73.99          40.76       -73.99   3/1/19 15:26
 2/3/19  231y    36.08        -94.2           36.07       -94.21   3/2/19 0:14
 3/3/19  305g    36.01        -78.92          36.01       -78.95   3/2/19 0:09
 3/3/19  328s    36.76        -119.83         36.74       -119.79  3/2/19 4:33
 3/3/19  286n    35.76        -78.78          35.78       -78.74   3/2/19 0:43
```

I want my output df to be any 2 orders or rows that satisfy the above conditions. What I am not sure of is how to calculate that for each row in the dataframe to return any two rows that satisfy those condtions.

I hope I am explaining my desired output correctly. Thanks for looking!

Comment: I am trying both solutions, but when I try both lines of code that compute the combinations, my notebook kernal keeps crashing. Is there anyway to resolve that?
@run-out

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is an optimal solution, but I didn't come up with something different. What I have done:

- created dataframe with all possible orders combination,
- computed all needed measures and for all of the combinations, I added those measures column to the dataframe,
- find the indices of the rows which fulfill the mentioned conditions.

The code:

```
#create dataframe with all combination 
from itertools import combinations

index_comb = list(combinations(trips.index, 2))#trip, your dataframe
col_names = trips.columns
orders1= pd.DataFrame([trips.loc[c[0],:].values for c in index_comb],columns=trips.columns,index = index_comb)
orders2= pd.DataFrame([trips.loc[c[1],:].values for c in index_comb],columns=trips.columns,index = index_comb)
orders2 = orders2.add_suffix('_1')
combined = pd.concat([orders1,orders2],axis=1)

from haversine import haversine

def distance(row):
    loc_0 = (row[0],row[1]) # (lat, lon)
    loc_1 = (row[2],row[3])
    return haversine(loc_0,loc_1,unit='mi')

#pickup diff
pickup_cols = ["pickup_long","pickup_lat","pickup_long_1","pickup_lat_1"]
combined[pickup_cols] = combined[pickup_cols].astype(float)
combined["pickup_dist_mi"] = combined[pickup_cols].apply(distance,axis=1)

#dropoff diff
dropoff_cols = ["dropoff_lat","dropoff_long","dropoff_lat_1","dropoff_long_1"]
combined[dropoff_cols] = combined[dropoff_cols].astype(float)
combined["dropoff_dist_mi"] = combined[dropoff_cols].apply(distance,axis=1)

#creation time diff
combined["time_diff_min"] = abs(pd.to_datetime(combined["created_time"])-pd.to_datetime(combined["created_time_1"])).astype('timedelta64[m]')

#Thresholds
Z = 600
Y = 400
X = 400

#find orders with below conditions
diff_time_Z = combined["time_diff_min"] < Z
pickup_dist_X =  combined["pickup_dist_mi"]<X
dropoff_dist_Y =  combined["dropoff_dist_mi"]<Y
contitions_idx = diff_time_Z & pickup_dist_X & dropoff_dist_Y
out = combined.loc[contitions_idx,["Order","Order_1","time_diff_min","dropoff_dist_mi","pickup_dist_mi"]]
```

The output for your data:

```
        Order Order_1  time_diff_min  dropoff_dist_mi  pickup_dist_mi
(0, 5)  234e    328s          573.0       322.988195      231.300179
(1, 2)  235d    253w          475.0         2.072803        0.896893
(4, 6)  305g    286n           34.0        19.766096       10.233550
```

Hope I understand you well and that will help.

Comment: Thanks :) 

When I run the code - my notebook at this line -

Keeps running and kernal fails is there something off with this code?

index_comb = list(combinations(df.index, 2))

@Rafzy15

Comment: is there any workaround so I can have the kernal not fail when running the that line? maybe since my df is larger than the sample df?

Comment: Hey, I did not have any problem with this code :( so, I guess that this could be related to memory. Did you try with the same data, but smaller amount (for example process only half of your  data set)? What I recommend you is to change the code to work with generator - `combinations(trips.index, 2)`  instead of creating the list. I will look at this later.

Comment: Yeah this is prob memory related bc of size of dataset around 500k rows. Would changing the code to that help? Am trying now! Thanks for responding :) @Rafzy15

Comment: It processed the code with your edit in your comment - but seems to be stuck here now - orders1= pd.DataFrame([df.loc[c[0],:].values for c in index_comb],columns=df.columns,index = index_comb)

Sorry for bothering @Rafzy15

Answer (score 2):

Using your dataframe as above. Drop the index. I'm presuming your created_time column is in datetime format.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic
```

Cross merge the dataframe to get all possible combinations of 'Order'.

```
df_all = pd.merge(df.assign(key=0), df.assign(key=0), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
```

Remove all the rows where the orders are equal.

```
df_all = df_all[-(df_all['Order_x'] == df_all['Order_y'])].copy()
```

Drop duplicate rows where Order_x, Order_y == [a, b] and [b, a]

```
# drop duplicate rows
# first combine Order_x and Order_y into a sorted list, and combine into a string
df_all['dup_order'] = df_all[['Order_x', 'Order_y']].values.tolist()
df_all['dup_order'] = df_all['dup_order'].apply(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x)))

# drop the duplicates and reset the index
df_all = df_all.drop_duplicates(subset=['dup_order'], keep='first')
df_all.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Create a column calculate the time difference in minutes.

```
df_all['time'] = (df_all['dt_ceated_x'] - df_all['dt_ceated_y']).abs().astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

Create a column and calculate the distance between drop offs.

```
df_all['dropoff'] = df_all.apply(
    (lambda row: geodesic(
        (row['dropoff_lat_x'], row['dropoff_long_x']),
        (row['dropoff_lat_x'], row['dropoff_long_y'])
    ).miles),
    axis=1
)
```

Create a column and calculate the distance between pickups.

```
df_all['pickup'] = df_all.apply(
    (lambda row: geodesic(
        (row['pickup_lat_x'], row['pickup_long_x']),
        (row['pickup_lat_x'], row['pickup_long_y'])
    ).miles),
    axis=1
)
```

Filter the results as desired.

```
X = 1500
Y = 2000
Z = 100

mask_pickups = df_all['pickup'] < X
mask_dropoff = df_all['dropoff'] < Y
mask_time = df_all['time'] < Z

print(df_all[mask_pickups & mask_dropoff & mask_time][['Order_x', 'Order_y', 'time', 'dropoff', 'pickup']])

Order_x Order_y  time      dropoff       pickup
10    235d    231y  53.0  1059.026620  1059.026620
11    235d    305g  48.0   260.325370   259.275948
13    235d    286n  82.0   249.306279   251.929905
25    231y    305g   5.0   853.308110   854.315567
27    231y    286n  29.0   865.026077   862.126593
34    305g    286n  34.0    11.763787     7.842526
```